# Accepting multiple lines of input from user via fgets()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm trying to accept multiple lines of 'address' from the user using `fgets` but I'm having a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` just as I leave the while loop. I can `printf` both the `address` and `part_of_address` variables while within the loop without any issues, while in the loop it works as expected. Once breaking free of the loop it catches fire.

```
// Define a char array called 'name' accepting up to 25 characters.
char name[25];
// Define a char array called 'part_of_address' accepting up to 80 characters.
char part_of_address[80];
// Define a char array called 'address' accepting up to 80 characters.
char address[80];

// Clean the buffer, just to be safe...
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {};

// Ask for the user to enter a name for the record using fgets and stdin, store
// the result on the 'name' char array.
printf("\nEnter the name of the user (RETURN when done):");
fgets(name, 25, stdin);

// Ask for the user to enter multiple lines for the address of the record, capture
// each line using fgets to 'part_of_address'
printf("\nEnter the address of the user (DOUBLE-RETURN when done):");
while (1)
{
    fgets(part_of_address, 80, stdin);
    // If the user hit RETURN on a new line, stop capturing.
    if (strlen(part_of_address) == 1)
    {
        // User hit RETURN
        break;
    }
    // Concatinate the line 'part_of_address' to the multi line 'address'
    strcat(address, part_of_address);
}

printf("This doesn't print...");
```

Comment: You most probably overflow `address` by repeatedly concatenating text to it.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs if the user never enters an address as well.

Comment: You can just `strcpy()` the first string, then `strcat()` the rest.

Comment: The problem is in your input and your mishandling of memory. On small names and addresses nothing segfaults http://ideone.com/rNWfO2

Comment: `address` is not initialized. `char address[80];` -> `char address[80] = "";`.

Comment: BTW: this kind of errors can be found easily with a debugger. Learn how to use one.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That was the problem. Adding `= ""` to all of the fields makes the code work as expected. I'm using Atom to write the code, and terminal to compile and test. We've been instructed by the professor not to use a debugger. :(

Comment: Then your professor isn't teaching you anything useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller even without a debugger you can use the so called "printf debugging", that means putting printf statements at strategic locations.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I know, did it myself when starting. But our CS-101 professors always encourages us to learn how to use debuggers. I had my fill of `printk` debugging when toying with Linux Kernel code.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, the comment was actually intended for the OP, not for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Michael Walz in comment, you use `strcat(address, part_of_address);` even at first time without having initialized `address`. As it is an automatic array, it contains undeterminated values, and you are invoking Undefined Behaviour. It is likely that even first `strcat` overwrites memory after the `address` array.

Just initialize the array with `char address[80] = "";` or `char address[80] = {'\0'};`